# htaccess redirect url with language and page parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm really lost in all the rules to redirect an htaccess and I can't find the perfect solution for my problem.
I'm trying to redirect my urls who looks like this :

```
http://mywebpage.eu/path/to/site/LANGUAGE/PAGE
```

who should redirect to

```
http://mywebpage.eu/path/to/site/index.php?lang=LANGUAGE&page=PAGE
```

but sometime they could be like this without PAGE or LANGUAGE

```
http://mywebpage.eu/path/to/site/LANGUAGE/
http://mywebpage.eu/path/to/site/PAGE/
```

who should redirect to

```
http://mywebpage.eu/path/to/site/index.php?lang=LANGUAGE&page=
http://mywebpage.eu/path/to/site/index.php?lang=&page=PAGE
```

(all these examples could end with "**/**" or not)

When I finaly get a part of something who's working, all my css/images/js/include(php) are 404 errored because of the addition of that virtual subfolder "/LANGUAGE/"...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /path/to/site/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

**Thanks a lot for your help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /path/to/site/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(?:/(.*))?/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?lang=&page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

For css/js/images you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/path/to/site/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude :) seems perfect !